# Polymorphic Step Definitions with Cucumber, PicoContainer & Conductor Framework

Tags: java, selenium, picocontainer, conductor-framework

The issue I'm having is that Locomotive is not being terminated after each Cucumber scenario is run.  Then I'm being left with orphaned Selenium processes, e.g.:

```
501 75709     1   0  1:29PM ??         0:00.05 /Users/rich/IdeaProjects/selenium/chromedriver.mac --port=45715
501 75720     1   0  1:29PM ??         0:00.04 /Users/rich/IdeaProjects/selenium/chromedriver.mac --port=12004
```

This is my PicoContainer setup class, so that it will inject an instance of Locomotive into each Cucumber scenario (which it does):

```
    public class CustomPicoFactory extends PicoFactory {

    public CustomPicoFactory() {
        addClass(Locomotive.class);
    } 
}
```

This entry is in my cucumber.properties file:

```
cucumber.api.java.ObjectFactory = CustomPicoFactory
```

Here is an example step definition class:

```
public class BorrowerSteps {

    Locomotive locomotive;

    public BorrowerSteps(Locomotive locomotive) {
        this.locomotive = locomotive;
    }
}
```

Is there some sort of cleanup method I can call after each Scenario is run?  Or a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: why are you injecting Locomotive instances? Shouldn't your test classes be extending Locomotive, like in the [examples](http://conductor.ddavison.io/examples/)? Maybe if you'd post a reproducable example of your test/step class it would make sense.

Comment: I'm injecting instances of Locomotive so that I can share the same instance between Cucumber steps in a scenario.  If I extended Locomotive on each Cucumber step definition class, I'd have multiple instances of locomotive per scenario.  I'll get to creating an example, so that things are clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the chromedriver is being left open because upon instantiation of a Locomotive object, the chromedriver is created.

It isn't killed until `driver.quit()` is called. In order to do that, you can call `locomotive.teardown()` or `locomotive.driver.quit()`

Comment: Many thanks @sircapsalot - I added an after scenario step that does exactly that.